# Randomly assign values into data frame/matrix of different size groups that meet multiple criteria

Tags: r

This is a follow on from a previous question [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792155/randomly-assign-people-into-different-size-groups-and-category), but adds an extra layer of complexity, hence a new question.

I have two groups (**39** and **380** in the example below). What I need to do is assign **889** people into the 39 groups consisting of between **2 to 7** people and the 380 groups consisting of between **2 to 6** people.

However, there is a constraint on the total number of people that can belong in certain sets of groups. In the example below that maximum value allowed for each row is in column X6.

Using the example below. If in row 2 there were 6 people assigned in column X2 and 120 people assigned in column X4 then the total of people would be 18(6*3)+240(120*2) = 258, so that would be fine as it would be under 324.

So what I am after for each row is a value of X1*X2 + X3*X4 (to make column X5) that is less or equal to X6 with the sum of X2 being 39, the sum of X4 being 380 and the total sum of X5 being 889. Ideally any solution would be as random as possible (so if repeated you would get a different solution if possible) and one that would work when the values are different to 889, 39 and 380.

Thanks!

```
DF <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 7, ncol = 6))
DF[,1] <- c(2:7,"Sum")
DF[7,2] <- 39
DF[2:6,3] <- 2:6
DF[7,4] <- 380
DF[7,5] <- 889
DF[1:6,6] <- c(359, 324, 134, 31, 5, 2)
DF[1,3:4] <- NA
DF[7,3] <- NA
DF[7,6] <- NA
```

**EDIT**

The phrasing of my problem may not be clearest. Here is an example of the code I am currently using and how it does not meet the criteria I set above

```
homeType=rep(c("a", "b"), times=c(39, 380))
H <- vector(mode="list", length(homeType))
for(i in seq(H)){
  H[[i]]$type <- homeType[i]
  H[[i]]$n <- 0
}

# Place people in houses up to max number of people
npeople <- 889
for(i in seq(npeople)){
  placed_in_house <- FALSE
  while(!placed_in_house){
    house_num <- sample(length(H), 1)
    if(H[[house_num]]$type == "a"){
      if(H[[house_num]]$n < 7){
        H[[house_num]]$n <- H[[house_num]]$n + 1
        placed_in_house <- TRUE
      }
    }
    if(H[[house_num]]$type == "b"){
      if(H[[house_num]]$n < 6){
        H[[house_num]]$n <- H[[house_num]]$n + 1
        placed_in_house <- TRUE
      }
    }
  }
}

# move people around to get up to min number of people
for(i in seq(H)){
  while(H[[i]]$n < 2){
    knock_on_door <- sample(length(H), 1)
    if( H[[knock_on_door]]$n > 2){
      H[[i]]$n <- H[[i]]$n + 1 # house i takes 1 person
      H[[knock_on_door]]$n <- H[[knock_on_door]]$n - 1 # house knock_on_door loses 1 person
    }
  }
}

Ha <- H[which(lapply(H, function(x){x$type}) == "a")]
Hb <- H[which(lapply(H, function(x){x$type}) == "b")]

Ha_T <- data.frame(t(table(data.frame(matrix(unlist(Ha), nrow=length(Ha), byrow=T)))))
Hb_T <- data.frame(t(table(data.frame(matrix(unlist(Hb), nrow=length(Hb), byrow=T)))))

DF_1 <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 7, ncol = 6))
DF_1[,1] <- c(2:7,"Sum")
DF_1[7,2] <- 39
DF_1[2:6,3] <- 2:6
DF_1[7,4] <- 380
DF_1[7,5] <- 889
DF_1[1:6,6] <- c(359, 324, 134, 31, 5, 2)
for(i in 1:nrow(Ha_T)){DF_1[as.numeric(as.character(Ha_T[i,1]))-1,2] <- Ha_T[i,3]}
for(i in 1:nrow(Hb_T)){DF_1[as.numeric(as.character(Hb_T[i,1])),4] <- Hb_T[i,3]}
DF_1$X5[1:6] <- (as.numeric(as.character(DF_1$X1[1:6]))*DF_1$X2[1:6])+(as.numeric(as.character(DF_1$X3[1:6]))*DF_1$X4[1:6])
DF_1$X7 <- DF_1$X2+DF_1$X4
DF_1[1,3:4] <- NA
DF_1[7,3] <- NA
DF_1[7,6] <- NA
```

Using this example the problem is row 2 in DF_1. The value in Column X7 (X2+X4) is greater than the permitted number shown in Column X6. What I need is a solution where the values in X7 are less or equal to the values in X6, but the sum of columns X2, X4 and X5 (X1*X2+X3*X4) equal 39, 380 and 889 respectively (although these numbers change depending on the data used).

Comment: If we're only allowed to sample between 2 and 6 for the fourth column how could it sum to 380?

Comment: are you sure the numbers in column x6 are correct? E.g it is impossible to assign anyone to row 6, because 1x7 > 2, and 1x6>2.  Also, there is only one way to assign anyone in row 5, which would be 1 in X4, and 0 in X2.

Comment: Same with row 1, which only has one input (x2), and a constraint x2 * 2 = 359. This gives 179.5, which is both greater than 7 and probably an illegal way to divide people ;)

Comment: This seems like it is just solving for a system of equations. Ignoring the fact that your coefficients are messed , I think you want to solve your system for a function rather than a value, and then sampling some initial values to imply values for the rest of your variables. Not sure how to do this in R

Comment: @bouncyball I have edited the question to illustrate the problem I have and hopefully clarified what I actually need as an output.

Comment: @dww The numbers are correct. I have added an example of the code I am currently using to show the problem I currently have and what I require as an output.

Comment: read the comments on the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793510/find-the-discrete-pair-of-x-y-that-satisfy-inequality-constriants

Answer (score 1):

The original description of the problem in the question is impossible to satisfy, as there are no values that can satisfy all these constraints.

> "So what I am after for each row is a value of X1*X2 + X3*X4 (to make
>   column X5) that is less or equal to X6 with the sum of X2 being 39,
>   the sum of X4 being 380 and the total sum of X5 being 889. "

However, following a restatement of the problem in the comments, the revised description of the problem can be solved as follows.

**Update: Solution based on clarification of the problem in comments**

According to a clarification in the comments

> "I am not actually filling the number of houses completely. I am just assigning the number of children into houses. This is why
>   'a' is 2 to 7 and 'b' is 2 to 6, as 'a' households will also include 1
>   adult and 'b' households 2. For a given area I know how many 2 to 8
>   person households there are (419), and how many 2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8
>   person households exist (359,324,134,31,5,2). I also know the total
>   number of households with either 1 (39) or 2 (380) adults, and how
>   many children there are (889 in my example)."

Based on this updated information we can do the following, in which we loop over 1) calculate how many more houses of each type can be allocated according to the criteria, 2) randomly select one of the house types that can still be allocated without breaching one of the rules 3) and repeat until all 889 children are in houses. Note that I use more descriptive column names here, to make it easier to follow the logic:

```
DT <- data.table(HS1 = 2:7, # type 1 house size
                 NH1 = 0,   # number of type 1 houses with children
                 HS2 = 1:6, # type 2 house size
                 NH2 = 0,   # number of type 2 houses with children
                 C = 0,     # number of children in houses
                 MaxNH = c(359, 324, 134, 31, 5, 2)) # maximum number of type1+type 2 houses
NR = DT[,.N]
set.seed(1234)
repeat {
  while (DT[, sum(C) < 889]) {
    DT[, MaxH1 := (MaxNH - NH1 - NH2)]
    DT[, MaxH2 := (MaxNH - NH1 - NH2)]
    DT[1,MaxH2 := 0 ]
    DT[MaxH1 > 39 - sum(NH1), MaxH1 := 39 - sum(NH1)]
    DT[MaxH2 > 380- sum(NH2), MaxH2 := 380- sum(NH2)]
    if (DT[, sum(NH1)] >= 39)  DT[, MaxH1 := 0]
    if (DT[, sum(NH2)] >= 380) DT[, MaxH1 := 0]

    if (DT[, all(MaxH1==0) & all(MaxH2==0)]) { # check if it is not possible to assign anyone else to a group
      print("No solution found. Check constraints or try again")
      break
    }
    # If you wish to preferentially fill a particular type of house, then change the probability weights in the next line accordingly
    newgroup = sample(2*NR, 1, prob = DT[, c(MaxH1, MaxH2)])
    if (newgroup > NR) DT[rep(1:NR, 2)[newgroup], NH2 := NH2+1] else DT[rep(1:NR, 2)[newgroup], NH1 := NH1+1]

    DT[, C := HS1*NH1 + HS2*NH2]
  }
  if (DT[, sum(C)==889]) break
}

DT[,1:6, with=F]
#   HS1 NH1 HS2 NH2   C MaxNH 
#1:   2   7   1   0  14   359 
#2:   3   7   2 218 457   324 
#3:   4  14   3  76 284   134  
#4:   5   9   4  14 101    31  
#5:   6   2   5   3  27     5 
#6:   7   0   6   1   6     2 

colSums(DT[, .(NH1, NH2, C)])
# NH1 NH2   C 
#  39 312 889
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example. If the number of people was 838, rather than 889, should your code above work? Or did you include it to illustrate one possible way of achieving my goal if the constraints were different?

Comment: Hi @Chris. The code I provided should be able to find solutions in cases where the constraints *can* be satisfied. However, the proof above simply demonstrates that it is impossible to assign more than 846 people given the constraints. It does not prove that a solution exists a solution for any specific number less than 846.  In fact, the maximum number that can be assigned will be considerably less than this because of the interactions between constraints that I mentioned....

Comment: ... You will need to relax the constraints considerably either by increasing the values in X6, and/or increasing the maximum column sums allowed, and/or reducing the number of people to assign. There is no code possible that can find a solution unless you relax these constraints enough for there to exist a possible solution.

Comment: Hi @dww. What makes this strange is, as I alluded to in another comment, these values come from a real life example so a solution should be possible. I shall have to go back and examine the raw data to try and figure what's going on.

Comment: @Chris I have updated the solution, based on the new information you provided in the comment. This should solve your problem now

Comment: Thanks for the new code, sorry for not making it clearer what I was after in my original question! However, one thing is that the output for NH2 is 312 when it needs to be 380. I can't see an obvious way of making sure the output of your code would guarantee NH1=39, NH2=380 and C=889

Comment: As you may have gathered, the problem I am having fits into a larger problem. Hence I tried to simplify as much as possible to make it as clear as possible. If any misunderstandings have been caused by my phrasing then that is my fault and I am very grateful for your help. I thought from my additional comment I had made it clear that the 39 and 380 values were the same. The 889 is a random number generated from the minimum required persons (39+380*2=838) with some extra added by a different process. So the 889 could easily be replaced by a number that works as long as it is above 838.

Comment: Again I didn't go into detail about this because it just further complicates things. However, your answer is clearly the best so thank you for spending the time to help. You have not wasted your time, I now have a potential way to solve something that has been causing my numerous problems for weeks!

Answer (score 0):

This code provides checks whether the generated data meet the criteria. With each iteration, it stops for the user decision to keep on trying. For me, the selection process never dropped below 348 b-houses with 2 people each and thus the result always violated the second condition (less than 324 houses). Should the a and b house types be offset in the df?

```
df <- data.frame(a=2:7, afreq=0, b=c(0,2:6), bfreq=0, housed=0, houses=500, correct=c(359, 324, 134, 31, 5, 2))

H <- data.frame(type=homeType, n=0) # using df instead of lists, easier for me

npeople <- 889

while(any(df$houses > df$correct)){

    H <- data.frame(type=homeType, n=0)

    # This code is yours, changed to df
    for(i in 1:npeople){
      placed_in_house <- FALSE
      while(!placed_in_house){
        house_num <- sample(nrow(H), 1)
        if(H$type[house_num] == "a"){
          if(H$n[house_num] < 7){
            H$n[house_num] <- H$n[house_num] + 1
            placed_in_house <- TRUE
          }
        }
        if(H$type[house_num] == "b"){
          if(H$n[house_num] < 6){
            H$n[house_num] <- H$n[house_num] + 1
            placed_in_house <- TRUE
          }
        }
      }
    }

    # Subsets of houses with lack of people and possible sources
    # This is iterative to randomize the full dataset
    Hempty <- which(H$n < 2)
    Hfull <- which(H$n >= 2)
    k <- 1 # effort counter

    while(length(Hempty) > 0){
        for(hempty in Hempty){
            knock_on_door <- sample(Hfull, 1)
            H$n[knock_on_door] <- H$n[knock_on_door] - 1 # moves from a full house
            H$n[hempty] <- H$n[hempty] + 1 # moves into an empty house
        }
        Hempty <- which(H$n < 2)
        Hfull <- which(H$n >= 2)
        print(paste("Iteration:", k, ", remaining empty houses:", length(Hempty)))
        k <- k + 1
    }

    # Frequencies how many houses house how many people
    freqs <- data.frame(table(H))
    df$afreq[match(freqs$n[freqs$type == "a"], df$a)] <- freqs$Freq[freqs$type == "a"]
    df$bfreq[match(freqs$n[freqs$type == "b"], df$b)] <- freqs$Freq[freqs$type == "b"]

    df$housed <- df[,1]*df[,2] + df[,3]*df[,4]
    df$houses <- df$afreq + df$bfreq

    # Check what is wrong with the occupancy and let user have a say
    print(df)
    if(any(df$houses > df$correct)){
        readline("There are more houses with a number of occupants than permitter. Hit [enter]")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. a and b are meant to be offset, although the real problem with the code I am using is that it will always assign the most people into the smallest category. So despite the improvements you have made, I think I am going to need an alternative approach.

Comment: @Chris If all houses need to be filled and there are only 889 people to fill 416 houses, most must be housed in pairs. Increase the number of people.

Comment: I am not actually filling the number of houses completely. I am just assigning the number of children into houses. This is why 'a' is 2 to 7 and 'b' is 2 to 6, as 'a' households will also include 1 adult and 'b' households 2. For a given area I know how many 2 to 8 person households there are (419), and how many 2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8 person households exist (359,324,134,31,5,2). I also know the total number of households with either 1 (39) or 2 (380) adults, and how many children there are (889 in my example). I should also point out this numbers are not made up, but are derived from reality.

Comment: @Chris I see now. However, I have problems writing a function to move children to available houses and it took all my available time the last two days. Sorry, I cannot help you.